# State Management - [Switching States, Replaying the Game]

Tags: java, user-input, slick2d, 2d-games, state-management

How to effectively switch states?Whenever I press the replay button, the two states shows alternatively (win & play). I believe that was an infinite loop but Eclipse does not print any errors.

When I tried [this](http://slick.ninjacave.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5466), it results to null.Thus, ending the game.
Could [this](http://kivistudio.com/2012/03/19/tutorial-a-very-simple-basic-game-state-management-sample-for-wp7-xna-games/) be the answer? But I don't understand his Update(). What to put exactly there?will that overwrite the update of the state class?

**Here is my code:**
stateID(2) is the Wins.java

**PlayGround.java**

```
   public static boolean bouncy = true;   
   public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws            SlickException{
             //if the user is successful, show winner state
            if(!bouncy){
                sbg.enterState(2);
            }
           //moves the image randomly in the screen
        new Timer(10,new ActionListener(){
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
              {
                  posX = (r.nextInt(TestProject4.appGC.getWidth()-75));
                  posY = (r.nextInt(TestProject4.appGC.getHeight()-75));
              }
         }).start();


    }          
    public void mousePressed(int button,int x,int y){
         //if the user pressed the mouse button And
         //if the user's coordinates is inside the hit area(rect)
        if((button == 0) && (rect.contains(x, y))){
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
              bouncy = false;
        }
    }
```

---

**Wins.java**

```
    @Override
public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta)throws SlickException {
    //replay game
    if(backToGame == true){
        sbg.enterState(state);
    }
}

public void mousePressed(int button,int x,int y){
     //if the user clicks the replay button
    if(button == 0){        
      if((x>160 && x<260)&&(y>280 && y<320)){
             if(Mouse.isButtonDown(0)){
                    backToGame = true;                      
                    state = 1;
             }
          }

          //exit button
          if((x>=360 && x<460)&&(y>280 && y<320)){
             if(Mouse.isButtonDown(0)){
                System.exit(0);
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you switch between both states again and again because both GameState objects are still in the same "state" (variables have still the same values) when you switch back.

Try:

```
if(!bouncy){
  bouncy = true; // next time we are in this game state it will not trigger immediately
  sbg.enterState(2);
}

if(backToGame == true){
  backToGame = false; // same here 
  sbg.enterState(state);
}
```

---

Previous answer:

Please check your if statement:

```
  if((x>160 && x<180)||(y>280 && y<320)){
```

You are checking whether the mouse is between some **x** coordinates `OR` some **y** coordinates.

I think you want to check whether the mouse is between some **x** `AND` some **y** coordinates:

```
  if((x>160 && x<180)&&(y>280 && y<320)){
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but it did not solve my problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two methods mousePressed() one in PlayGround.java and the other in Wins.java.
The application is clearly using the Playground.java Code.

Adding the button detection code into the PlayGround.java may solve the problem.

Other wise explicitly calling the mousePressed() method in Wins from PlayGround.java 
may work as well.

Adding comments help. 
It can show your train of thought for a project, Helps others to try and see what you are doing.
In fleshing out a complex method I comment excessively at first, weeding out obvious comments through iterations of debugging and code review.
I also helps when others are viewing your code.
Remember There are no stupid comments, only stupid people.

Comment: I removed the comments because others might get annoyed or something. I'll edit and add comments now. btw, thanks!

Comment: thank you @user3931253 for your suggestion. I tried it but nothing changed :( btw, I edited my problem statement.